# Message App show empty list on Mac OS X Catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, ichat

I'm on a Mac OS X Catalina. I have no idea what's wrong with my Message app lately. I can send out message, I can't see list of previous messages. It's empty.

[image]

I've also tried, clicked on the `Sync Now` button

[image]

and even tried sign out, and sign back in.

## Have you guys seen this before ?

Comment: Have you tried Safe Mode, a reinstall of macOS Catalina, and have you tried using a different iCloud account? If the issue persists after all of these, I would try creating a new macOS User Account and testing this.